# How to return a reference, then increment iterator

Tags: c++, stl, operators

Please consider the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    //some useful unique data
};

std::vector<Foo> foos;
std::vector<Foo>::iterator foo_iter;
//populate with a load of Foo objects.

Foo& getNextFoo()
{
    return *foo_iter++;
}
```

What I wish `getNextFoo()` to do is, as you might expect, is dereference the iterator, return a reference, and then post increment the iterator.

I'm not convinced this will work, and I am a bit hazy on operator precedence, and would appreciate some guidance as to how to achieve this

Comment: If it confuses you it will probably confuse everybody else. we are not all operator precedence experts. What's wrong with two lines and make it easy for us silly people coming after you?

Comment: It seems fine to me... Did you run any tests that gave you unexpected results? @systemcpro there is no succint way to do this in separate statements as the increment is logically after the return statement, which of course cannot happen in actual c++ code

Comment: Perhaps I should have also mentioned parenthesis too as in the answer below. This is much easier for me to read than looking up operator precedence rules. Anything really that doesn't rely on knowing the intimate details of operator precedence really. We are not ll gurus.

Comment: Writing good code is about how maintainable it is.  The ability to return to it in 6 months and look at it and not question if there's a bug is important.  For that reason, +1 to 2 lines.

Comment: I was writing this code in a larger project initially, but yes, I wrote a quick test program and all works fine. I just wasn't convinced it would do what I thought. Bad practice on my part for not writing the test before asking.

Comment: This seems like a confusing interface. Why not return the iterator itself with an end iterator to check against? I'd be worried someone calls `getNextFoo()` repeatedly without realizing that at some point it will try to dereference `foos.end()` which won't go well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Foo& getNextFoo()
{
    return *foo_iter++;
}
```

The post-increment operator [has higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than dereference, so this will work as you intend.

If you want to make it more explicit, you could also say

```
return *(foo_iter++);
```